# wamp configuration showing instead of my website page

Tags: redirect, joomla, wamp

I installed WAMP server in my computer and successfully configured my IP to redirect to my domain but my problem is when I type my IP or Domain name I am redirected to the WAMP configuration page and not to http://mydomain.com/project.

I am running Joomla CMS.

Comment: How did you configure your IP to re-direct to your domain ? Did you add a virtual hosts config ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the purpose of WAMP.  You don't install WAMP then redirect anything to your domain.  There is no point in the process you describe.

If you are attempting to setup Joomla on your localhost or setup a development environment please check this: [Joomla Development](http://docs.joomla.org/Setting_up_your_workstation_for_joomla_development) or [Local Joomla](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36633/Configuring-Joomla-in-Step-by-Step-Manner)